# getting numeric dataframe after sapply in R

Tags: r, arrays, dataframe, matrix

I have the following object:

```
df <- structure(c("2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "0", "0", "2", "2", "2", 
"2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "0", "0", "2", 
"2", "2"), .Dim = c(5L, 5L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("GID7173723", 
"GID4878677", "GID88208", "GID346403", "GID268825")))
```

When I run `class(df)` I get this:

```
[1] "matrix" "array"
```

What is a matrix and what is an array here ? I thought matrix and array are essentially the same thing.

I would like to get `df` into a numeric dataset as well.

Comment: `sapply` has default `simplify = TRUE`. Read `?sapply`.

Comment: it does not change anything just tried i still get `[1] "matrix" "array" `

Comment: Hard to tell what causes the array class. Can you share your sapply(...) command ?

Answer (score 0):

As explained in `?array`, "A two-dimensional array is the same thing as a matrix." But arrays can have more than 2 dimensions.

If you wish to remove the class array, you can force it by `class(df) <- "matrix"` (though you could have unintended effects).

Comment: but why there are both statements in , shouldn't be only `'matrix'` or `'array'` since what I have is a single object

Comment: R objects can have multiple classes. In your case, a matrix is a special kind of array. Therefore it has the general class "array" and a more precise class "matrix".

Comment: I see, multiple classes. Thanks